# How to switch to other Android Ui elements, by using Ui Automator classes

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I am using Android Ui Automator for the Functional testing of Contacts app. My mobile is LG D model.
Unable to switch to other Android Ui elements, I have tried the below code
By using UiObject and even the UiScrollable classes.

```
    UiScrollable phoneContSwipe = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true));

    UiObject nameTest=phoneContSwipe.getChild(new UiSelector().text("Name"));
    nameTest.setText("Ramu");

    UiObject phoneText=phoneContSwipe.getChild(new UiSelector().text("Phone"));
    phoneText.setText("11111111111");
```

What is happening is, the nameText and phoneText are entering in the same field.

Comment: Hello Hi, and i have used the direct code even, for the automating the contactsAdding. Like UiObject obj1= new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Name"));   obj1.setText("Ramu"); . Both of the 'nameText' and 'phoneText' elements are present at the same Ui page.

I thought scrolling is not happening. Then i used the UiScrollable class.
Even it did not work

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected

```
mDevice.findObject(By.clazz("android.widget.EditText").text(Pattern.compile("Name")).pkg("com.android.contacts")).setText("Ramu");
mDevice.findObject(By.clazz("android.widget.EditText").text(Pattern.compile("Phone")).pkg("com.android.contacts")).setText("11111111111");
```

It was generated automatically using [Text Input Feature](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester-public/wiki/Features#text-input) of [CulebraTester](http://culebra.dtmilano.com/).